Logical Replication Initial Sync Errors Not Fond In Log (sync_error_count > 0)
I'm using Postgres 15.2
The query below returns value greater than 0 and I also see several tables stuck in srsubstate 'f', but there are no errors in Kubernets postgres pod log.
select sync_error_count from pg_stat_subscription_stats

Where can I find what are the initial sync errors that the sync_error_count  indicate that occurred

What might cause srsubstate to remain at state 'f'.  I need to recreate the subscription several times before all tables are in state 'r'


